# Are the Canadian National Topographic System (NTS) maps available freely online?

Tags: data, web-service, maps, download, canada

I'd really like a seamless service of the Canadian topo maps, similar to ArcGIS Online USA Topographic Maps, http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4ee3622f0bfd41eea55ffa83aaf31a9f

If there is no service, is there a download site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the main Toporama WMS site is unavailable, [www.AlaskaMapped.org](http://www.alaskamapped.org/) has the seamless canadian 250k topos scanned from NTS paper maps under the [BDL Extras](http://www.alaskamapped.org/data/wms-wfs-wcs-web-service-feeds#web-mapping-services) service (also see [here](http://www.alaskamapped.org/data/gallery#wms-extras)). In the online map browser it's called the *SDMI.Topo* layer.

Toporama is is more up to date, has better resolution (1:50k) and let's you grab/leave-out certain layers while Alaska Mapped has better performance (and [Arcgis layers](http://www.alaskamapped.org/data/arcgis-layer-files) if you want them).

Comment: Thanks. The BDL extras is what I was looking for (but hoping for the 1:50k scale).  The vector based maps (toporama and ArcGIS World Topo are nice, but in the remote areas (where things haven't changed much) the annotation on the scanned maps is really nice (at the right scale).

Answer (score 3):

The FTP site is (much faster to get the data downloaded)

ftp://ftp2.cits.rncan.gc.ca/pub/

To see them on Google Maps (copy and paste long url)

```
http://members.bellatlantic.net/~vze2h6gy/papabear/BM_Station_GMap.html#width=1024&height=800&title=1&t=topo&z=16&object={station:%22QH0513%22,lat:45.333095544,lng:-71.01308085,designation:%22MARBLE%20IBC%22,status:%22Not%20Found%22,date:%227/12/2006%22,scaled:0,type:%22Survey%20disk%22,agency:%22IBC%22,condition:%22%22}
```

from:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/aa34d789185a1349/9ad16acdba574157

Answer (score 2):

ArcGIS.com has the [Canada Topo Map](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=1bb9a810f5d1443e8727dfeba75f69af) service which mashes together data from a number of sources -- from Canvec (which drives the already mentioned Toporama) to the deprecated National Topographic Database to TeleAtlas. The result is a bit disjointed and often inaccurate, at least in the areas that I'm familiar with, but might be okay for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a download site for Canadian digital topo maps.

http://geogratis.gc.ca/geogratis/en/product/search.do?id=CB864DC7-25A1-5136-57F4-C095CE1C6A6D

Edit:

Actually after digging around a little more, this may be closer to what you are looking for.
http://geogratis.gc.ca/geogratis/en/service/toporama.html

Comment: The site seems to be down (at least I can't reach it).  I'll try later.

Comment: I've had not trouble with it, but try the link for the home page.  http://geogratis.gc.ca/geogratis/en/index.html

Comment: The services link sounds promising, but I still can't get to any of the links;  I'll take it up with our network police.  Thanks.

Comment: there's a lower performing backup mirror at http://wmsmir.cits.rncan.gc.ca/wms/toporama (found on [this page](http://geogratis.cgdi.gc.ca/geogratis/en/service/toporama.html) )

Comment: the link Zachary posted goes to the "print ready" CanMatrix files, which are not geo-referenced. There also geotiff CanMatrix files, with collars, [here](http://geogratis.gc.ca/geogratis/en/product/search.do?id=CB864DC7-25A1-5136-57F4-C095CE1C6A6D).  De-collared, georeferenced and colour balanced CanMatrix - National Topographic Series (NTS) maps scanned at 150dpi - at 250k and 50k scales can be purchased on dvd from MapTown as [eTopo](http://www.maptown.com/etopo.html) for a reasonable price - $100 per province/territory.(No restrictions on re-use and distribtion, standard NRCAN data license)

Comment: @Zachary, feel free to fold my comments into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://www.canmaps.com/) what you are looking for, download wise? They are collared still though.

Comment: It looks like the collared maps are only available for purchase hard copy or on DVD.  The downloadable maps seems to be single tiles as un-referenced gif files.  In addition, the downloadable version is not the scanned/cropped map, but some digital imitation with poor annotation.  Am I missing something?